# Functions and Integration

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Let $y=f(x)$ be differential function which satisfies $$f(x)= x+\int_0^1x^2zf(z)dz+\int_0^1xz^2f(z)dz$$ then $$f\left(-\frac 94\right)=$$

A) $-\frac 49$

B) $\frac 49$

C) $-1$

D) $0$

Comment: I tried integration by parts but ended up by getting an answer that is even not in the options.

Comment: @GAVD: substituting $x=-9/4$ just leads you nowhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As

$$f(x)= x+x^2\int_0^1zf(z)dz+x\int_0^1z^2f(z)dz,$$

the function is clearly a quadratic polynomial of the form

$$f(x)=ax^2+bx.$$

Then evaluating the integrals,

$$\begin{cases}a=\dfrac a4+\dfrac b3,\\b=1+\dfrac a5+\dfrac b4.\end{cases}$$

After resolution,

$$a\left(-\frac94\right)^2-b\frac94=0.$$

Comment: how did you evaluated the integral?

Comment: @SanyamYadvendra: the integrands are mere polynomials, aren't they ?

Comment: @SanyamYadvendra: you missed my first sentence then (if not the whole answer).

Comment: It isn't provided in the question but I assume they are.

Comment: @SanyamYadvendra: ok, you did miss it.

Comment: Oh Sorry. I got it now, Thanks.